# Let $\chi_A :X \to \Bbb R$ the characteristic function of $A$. Show that $\chi_A$ is cont at $p \in X$ iff $p \notin \partial A$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $\chi_A :X \to \Bbb R$ the characteristic function of $A$. Show that $\chi_A$ is continuous at $p \in X$ iff $p \notin \partial A$.

Suppose that $\chi_A$ is continuous at $p$ and that $p \in \partial A$. If $p \in \partial A$, then there exists nbhd $U_p$ such that there is $z \in U_p$ for which $\chi_A(z)=0$ and $y \in U_p$ for which $\chi_A(y)=1$.

Pick now $U=(-1/2, 1/2)$ a nbhd of $\chi_A(z)$. Then $\chi_A^{-1}(U)= X \setminus A$ which isn't a open neighborhood of $p$. So $\chi_A$ cannot be continuous.

Does this work? I don't know if I am applying the definitions correctly.

Comment: When you write $\chi_A(z)$, what is $z$? Did you mean $p$ instead? And why is $(-1/2,1/2)$ such a neighbourhood? You are assuming $z\notin A$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $p \in \partial A$. We show that exists a open interval $I$ of $\chi_A(p)$ such that $U_p= \chi_A^{-1}(I)$ is no open in $X$. If $\chi_A(p)=0$, take $I =(-1/2,1/2)$ and, If $\chi_A(p)=1$, take $I =(1/2,3/2)$. In any case, $U_p= \chi_A^{-1}(I)$ is no open in $X$, because $U_p$ open implies that $U_p$ contains points of $X$ and $X\setminus A$. But It is Impossible, since $\chi_A(U_p) \subset (-1/2,1/2)$ or $\chi_A(U_p) \subset (1/2,3/2) $. Then $\chi_A$ is discontinuous in $p$.